# Sort BuddyPress Activity Stream by Profile Field (Location)?

Tags: php, sql, wordpress, buddypress

I have a Nationwide BuddyPress website, so the activity stream can become confusing since people from all over are posting updates/content. I'd like to give members the ability to sort the activity based on their chosen location in their profile (drop down).

If a person wants to view a BuddyPress stream from members in New York, then they should be able to... Not based on GeoLocation but on the state selected in their profile.

How can I filter activity based on the users location, which is chosen via drop down menu in Users > Profile Fields > State ?

Someone had mentioned - "Another approach is filtering on sql query which may be a little bit more efficient." but I'm not sure where to start with that one :(

Comment: Anyone? Is this not possible?

Comment: Hired a freelancer to solve the issue. thank you